# Confusion between Redirect and RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm studying for a MS certificate (70-515).
I'm a confused with what I find online and what I read in a practice test.
A few questions on SO state that using a RedirectToAction is sending the browser a 302, thus causing it to change it's url in the address bar.

But this is a question from 1 of the practice tests:

QUESTION:

> The MVC Home controller currently has only the default Index action. The relevant code is shown in the following code example.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Hello!";
    return View();
}
```

> You need to create an action named FindID that displays the ID parameter entered as part of the path. If the path does not include an ID parameter, ASP.NET must process the Index action without changing the URL in the browser's address bar, and must not throw an exception.
>   Which code segment should you use?

CORRECT ANSWER:

```
public ActionResult FindID(int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    ViewData["Message"] = "ID is " + id.ToString();
    return View();
}
```

EXPLANATION:

> You can use the RedirectToAction form of ActionResult to cause MVC to process a different action from within an action. MVC abandons the current action and processes the request as if the route had led directly to the action you redirect to. Essentially, this is equivalent to calling Server.Transfer in a standard ASP.NET application.
>
> The Redirect ActionResult sends an "HTTP Error 302 - Found" response to the browser, which causes the browser to load the specified URL. This changes the address that appears in the address bar.

So:
- Does a RedirectToAction leave the URL in browser untouched?
- Does a Redirect change the URL in browser?
- Is the explanation of the practice test correct? From that I understand that RedirectToAction does NOT do a 302.

Comment: ok, so it seems that what is written in the certification practice test is WRONG (horrible!). No correct answer was available. I wonder what I should do if I get exactly that question on the exam. I guess I will answer the same as is now marked as correct in the test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> You can use the RedirectToAction form of ActionResult to cause MVC to process a different action from within an action. MVC abandons the current action and processes the request as if the route had led directly to the action you redirect to. Essentially, this is equivalent to calling Server.Transfer in a standard ASP.NET application.

This is incorrect.

Both the RedirectToRouteResult (RedirectToAction) and RedirectResult perform a 302 redirect, resulting in the URL in the browser changing.

To return the Index result without changing the url the code would actually be:

```
public ActionResult FindID(int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
        return View("index");
    ViewData["Message"] = "ID is " + id.ToString();
    return View();
}
```

However, I would not recommended this approach. If I make a request to `mysite.com/products/some-product` and `some-product` does not exist, then I should inform the user of that with the relevant status code (also important for search engines).

If the sole purpose of your FindID action is to do something with the id parameter, then it should not be nullable/optional. This way the FindID action would not be invoked if an ID was not specified.

Comment: if RedirectToAction != Server.Transfer, then how would you do a Server.Transfer in MVC?

Comment: @TweeZz: You don't have to make a transfer as you are not in the view yet. You just return a different ActionResult from the controller to use a different view.

Comment: Ok, so long story short: Both RedirectToAction and Redirect do a 302, RedirectToAction simply allows you not to write a complete URL yourself, but to specify an action. Internally it's exactly the same. Right?

Comment: That's correct. Also I demonstrate in my answer how you would do the equivalent of Server.Transfer - just by calling Index() directly.

Comment: @Ben afaik, return Index(); would do what Index method does but then would try to FindID view. This is not completely right since we want to return Index view. I guess you would have to do and Index(); and return View("Index");

Comment: @petho well spotted. I've updated my answer. Just to reiterate, you **should** use the Redirect method.

Answer (score 9):

The documentation for the [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx) method tells us that it does send a 302 response:

> "Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action."

Examining the code in the dll reveals that it does return a `RedirectToRouteResult` object, which causes a redirect, so the documentation is correct:

```
protected internal virtual RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) {
  RouteValueDictionary routeValueDictionaries;
  if (this.RouteData == null) {
    routeValueDictionaries = RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues(actionName, controllerName, null, routeValues, true);
  } else {
    routeValueDictionaries = RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues(actionName, controllerName, this.RouteData.Values, routeValues, true);
  }
  return new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValueDictionaries);
}
```

The correct answer to the test question would be to use a different view:

```
public ActionResult FindID(int? id) {
  if (!id.HasValue) {
    ViewData["Message"] = "Hello!";
    return View("Index");
  }
  ViewData["Message"] = "ID is " + id.ToString();
  return View();
}
```

This will use the view `Index`, instead of the view `FindID` that is returned by the parameterless call `View()`.

Comment: I find this whole thing uber confusing :(