# What is the difference between Redirect and RedirectToAction in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between `Redirect` and `RedirectToAction` other than their return type?
When do we use each? Explanation with any real life scenario would help me greatly.

I was looking at [Confusion between Redirect and RedirectToAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477253/confusion-between-redirect-and-redirecttoaction), but, to me, it looks like the answer is more specific towards handling `id` parameter and returning proper view.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` lets you construct a redirect url to a specific action/controller in your application, that is, it'll use the route table to generate the correct URL.

`Redirect` requires that you provide a full URL to redirect to.

If you have an action `Index` on controller `Home` with parameter `Id`:

1. You can use `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { id = 5 })` which will generate the URL for you based on your route table.
2. You can use `Redirect` but must construct the URL yourself, so you pass `Redirect("/Home/Index/5")` or however your route table works.
3. You can't redirect to `google.com` (an external URL) using `RedirectToAction`, you must use `Redirect`.

`RedirectToAction` is meant for doing 302 redirects within your application and gives you an easier way to work with your route table.

`Redirect` is meant for doing 302 redirects to everything else, specifically external URLs, but you can still redirect within your application, you just have to construct the URLs yourself.

**Best Practices:** Use `RedirectToAction` for anything dealing with your application actions/controllers. If you use `Redirect` and provide the URL, you'll need to modify those URLs explicitly when your route table changes.

Comment: It means Redirect can also take you to completely different URL Vs RedirectToAction  is only limited to the current application. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: great answer. Thnaks for effort

Comment: Another key difference is that `RedirectToAction` sends POSTed form data to the next action. If you POST a field called "Name" with value "John", and the next action looks for a field called "Name", you will see the value "John" on that next action. You can clear these POSTed values by running `TempData.Clear();`.

Comment: Thanks for the very simple answer.

Comment: Are there any performance differences between this two ways of redirecting?

Comment: Any difference will be negligible. If we compare a redirect to a route within our application, the only additional work the `RedirectToAction` over `Redirect` has to do is figure out the route table which should be very fast as most of that is cached.

I would always use `RedirectToAction` to allow you to change routes in the future and not worry about breaking existing redirects.

Comment: @Omar If Index is HTTPGet, how can we use RedirectToAction since it will only look for the HttpPost in the controller?