# What are different Redirect methods in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone tell me about the different Redirect methods in ASP.NET MVC 5? I have user `Redirect`, `RedirectToAction`, `RedirectPermanent`, but I am wondering which one to use in which scenario.

Please describe all the Redirect methods available in ASP.NET MVC 5 apart from these.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Redirect and RedirectToAction in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198909/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I want to know about other redirecting techniques apart from these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Redirect - Redicect to the specified url (HTTP 302)
- RedirectPernament - Same as Redicect but with HTTP 301 response
- RedirectToAction - Redirect to the action (HTTP 302)
- RedirectToActionPernament - Same as RedirectToAction but with HTTP 301 response
- RedirectToRoute - Redicect to the route (HTTP 302)
- RedirectToRoutePernament - Same as RedirectToRoute but with HTTP 301 response

All redirect internally do the same (HTTP 302 or HTTP 301). Methods differ how they resolve url to redirect:

- Redirect use url passed as parameter
- RedirectToAction generates url from action name or action name and controller name
- RedirectToRoute generates url from route name

Answer (score 1):

You can using response to redirect like:

```
Response.Redirect("yoururl");//you can use route like: Response.Redirect("~/Home/About");
```