# MVC Redirect to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sharepoint-apps

I have a controller which processes an uploaded file. 
In that controller, I return the user to a SharePoint list depending on the successful parsing of that file. I am able to enter a direct URL, but I am opening this page in a form so I need to change the `window.top.location` instead of just `window.location`. I tried doing this a few ways such as returning a JavaScript result, but I received some browser warning messages I'd like to avoid.

I ended up making a partial razor view which grabs a parameter from the query string in order to determine which list it should go to. The function works fine, but the page is seemingly inactive when I return it using:

```
return Redirect("~/Parsing/ParsingRedirector?List=MasterDealer");
```

My page exists in the folder, but I get an error stating "The resource cannot be found. " 
Any reason why that's happening? I admittedly don't have a full understanding of MVC or even close to it at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("ParsingRedirector", "Parsing", new { List = "MasterDealer"});
```

Comment: This actually produced the same result as above. My issue was related to a misnamed view. However, I'm wondering if your approach is a better route to take for the line I added or if it shouldn't matter?

Comment: RedirectToAction is type safe. The compiler can catch the error during compilation instead of runtime. Lets say you somehow renamed the `Parsing` Controller to something else, with `RedirectToAction` the code will not compile, you can immediately fix it.

Comment: Hi @user3362735, Sorry I am wrong on the above comment. I have Resharper in my Visual Studio and it is Resharper catching the error not Visual Studio. For the correct answer to your question, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198909/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help:
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4XDc110313-return-View()-vs-return-RedirectToAction()-vs-return-Redirect()-vs-return-RedirectToRoute().html

Keep in mind that, per that article, in the case of Redirect "you have to specify the full URL to redirect."