# Core 3.0 Redirect to Action not working in Dynamic Route

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can access Action when I go over the link, but when I do RedirectToAction, I get an error "No route matches the supplied values.".
When I use "orders/list" route. I come to List action but I cannot come to Index action after redirect.

OrdersController.cs

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult List()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Orders");
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

TranslationTransformer.cs

```
public class TranslationTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
    {
        private readonly TranslationDatabase _translationDatabase;

        public TranslationTransformer(TranslationDatabase translationDatabase)
        {
            _translationDatabase = translationDatabase;
        }

        public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            return values; 
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<TranslationTransformer>("{controller}/{action}");
            });
```

Comment: It's been a little while since you asked this question. If you have any update on this behavior or reliable information about what's happening, it would be much appreciated. I've been spinning my wheels with this same issue for some time today. I posted my current solution as an answer, but would be interested to know more about what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Orders");
```

to

```
return Redirect("/Orders/Index");
```

Here is a working demo:

Controller:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult List()
        {
            return Redirect("/Orders/Index");
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: It can be considered a correct answer but do you know why RedirectToAction is not working?

Comment: The biggest difference I known between RedirectToAction and Redirect is that Redirect can go to an external URL.But I don't known why only Redirect can be used in your code.Here is a  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198909/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc#:~:text=RedirectToAction%20is%20meant%20for%20doing,to%20construct%20the%20URLs%20yourself.) about their difference.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today, and what seems to have fixed it (so far) in my project is adding a second endpoint in `Startup.Configure`.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    string defaultPattern = "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}";

    endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<MyTranslationTransformer>(defaultPattern);
    
    // This is the second endpoint I'm referring to:
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: defaultPattern);
});
```

I'm not certain *exactly* why this is working. I tried it after I read [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12997#issuecomment-506092274), noticed multiple endpoints in the examples, and tried the one that was present in the original project template generated by Visual Studio.

My current thought is basically just "Hmmm, need to supply a default route it seems."  However, why it appears to only affect `RedirectToAction` confuses me. Perhaps there are other methods affected that I haven't noticed which might shed light on the underlying mechanism.