# How to determine which view to redirect to using ViewModels?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently using ViewModels to bind to all my CRUD operations, but there are some action methods only returning partial views:

```
public ActionResult Create(int parentId)
{
    var viewModel = new MyCreateViewModel();
    return PartialView("_Create", viewModel);
}
```

These actions will be called from different views (different entities) via AJAX, and displayed in a jQuery dialog. The dialog buttons will handle the `POST`ing of the form via `$("#form").submit()`, and another action method will process the form, **ideally redirecting to the parent view that called the partial view**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int parentId, MyCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    //Process the viewModel, map to EF models and persist to the database

    return RedirectToAction(/*What should I insert here?*/);
}
```

Since I do not know which view is `POST`ing to this method, how can I know which view should I redirect to?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a string property to your viewModel that contains the name of the view you want to return

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int parentId, MyCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    //Process the viewModel, map to EF models and persist to the database

    return RedirectToAction(viewModel.ViewToRender);
}
```

Comment: I have thought of this option before. Does that mean I should also pass one extra parameter to store the view name for the `GET` action method? Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess the view that initiated the post will know which view to redirect to, so I guess it's not necessary to initially return that in the GET for each particular main. I can't think of an easier way to do this, unless you can somehow infer it from the other data in your view model

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused...if the view name is not passed in the `GET` action method, then where should I populate your `viewModel.ViewToRender` property?

Comment: If you're doing a form post you could stick it in a hidden field on the page. That will be posted along with the form

Comment: However that hidden field will also be dynamic (since it depends on which view is calling the partial view) so I still have to pass it into the `GET` action method...

Comment: Ok, I guess it depends on your circumstance. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but I figured you could hard code it outside the model in the main views that initiate the posts

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect in client side instead of doing that in the action method.
In the action method, you can return a result indicating the operation is success or fail. In the client side, use $.ajax to handle the result

```
        $('#form').submit(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        if (self.valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: self.attr('action'),
                data: self.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Success == true) {
                        //redirect
                    } else{
                        //Error handling
                    }
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                        //Error handling
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: The original post action has to return something though.

Comment: @TGH I think @Teddy means I should change the `POST` action method to `return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` then handle the Json inside the ajax `success` handler

Comment: @TGH I think RedirectToAction in fact is equal to redirect in client side, to return a view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477253/confusion-between-redirect-and-redirecttoaction . It looks like redirect to action will be similar to a Server.Transfer, so you will save one server round trip, compared to a regular redirect

Comment: hmm...I am still skeptical on which approach to take, client-side or server-side? Any best practice or recommendations?